KaTeX mhchem Extension Not Working in Svelte - Unable to Render \ce{} Command
I'm using KaTeX in a Svelte project to render chemical equations with the \ce{} command, but the mhchem extension isn't working. Other extensions like copytex load successfully.
<script lang="ts">
    import katex from 'katex';

    export function renderMath(math: string, displayMode = false) {
        return katex.renderToString(math, {
            displayMode,
            throwOnError: false
        });
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
        defer
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/contrib/mhchem.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ifpG+NlgMq0kvOSGqGQxW1mJKpjjMDmZdpKGq3tbvD3WPhyshCEEYClriK/wRVU0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
</svelte:head>

{@html renderMath('\\ce{H2O}')}

What I've Tried:

Importing mhchem.min.js script
Various configuration options
Different KaTeX rendering methods
Confirmed other extensions like copytex work correctly

Error:
Renders nothing or throws an "Undefined control sequence" error for \ce{}
Environment:

Svelte
KaTeX 0.16.11
Vite

Questions:

How can I properly load the mhchem extension in Svelte?
Are there any specific configuration steps needed for Svelte?


Solved!
<script lang="ts">
    import katex from 'katex';
    import 'katex/contrib/mhchem';

    export function renderMath(math: string, displayMode = false) {
        return katex.renderToString(math, {
            displayMode,
            throwOnError: false
        });
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
</svelte:head>

{@html renderMath('\\ce{H2O}')}

Importing works via:
import katex from '
import 'katex/contrib/mhchem';

